# SharePoint: How to get Top 5 records by using CAML query from a list

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have already created a webpart to show the data from list, but I really want is to only show top 5 records from that list (by using CAML query).

Does anyone know how to do this? Many thanks.

```
<Query>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could set the RowLimit property of your SPQuery object.

The `<RowLimit>` tag is in the schema definition of a view (direct child of <`View>`) and therefore cannot be nested inside a `<Query>` tag.

Comment: If I use this query - <Query><Where></Where></Query><View><RowLimit Paged='False'>10</RowLimit></View> - I'm getting an error 'There are multiple root elements'. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not put <View> in the Query; the SPQuery object has a separate property called View which you need to use, and also a RowLimit if I remember correctly

Answer (score 10):

The below code shows top 5 records from the list (by using CAML query).

```
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
spQuery.RowLimit = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct other simply caml queries try this tool.
http://www.camldesigner.com/

P.s. tool doesn`t construct a "paginate" caml queries with SPListItemCollectionPosition.